# DB Connect fail: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, my.cnf

Ubuntu Mysql service fails to manually start or auto start. The mysql server was running, then we change ip address and it stops working. I read many articles including this stackoverflow site but many of suggestions I did try did not work and I think that is many of them do not explain why.

In my case the reason is because the mysql-server binding address in my.cnf file is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why you get this error message:

> "DB Connect fail: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"

But the cause is laying in

> "/etc/mysq/my.cnf"

file. There is something wrong with that file or it is missing etc ... In my case **it is the ip address change**. Switch to root user

> "sudo -s"
>   or using "sudo" command

to open up the file **my.cnf** and change the ip address to the correct ip address (this should be the ip address of the server where mysql is running) it looks like this:

> "bind-address = 111.222.333.444"

then restart the mysql service with

> "sudo service mysql restart"

that will work!

Note: This similar error message

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")

Caused by wrong password so you see they are tricky, and be careful!